# How to logout when a new page is opened

Tags: javascript, php

So, I have a signing in website.

I have it that when the user closes the tab it logouts from the page. 
But when the user signs in and then on the same page he opens a new page E.g. google ( he types the page link in the url box and presses enter ). Google being opened, and then when he clicks back button he gets back to the page as signed in. How can I make it logout ?

Please if something is not clear, comment it and I will reply.

Thanks for your time

Comment: can you include your sample code please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use javascript window.onbeforeunload event, for example

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
    // delete login cookie
}
```

but I am not sure it will work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this out but it doesn't let me open the page first time. So, Whenever I try to open the page it ends the session and redirects me to the index page. I want that happen only when they open a new page after signing in. Any ideas how to sort it out ?